# Se utilizó un número incorrecto de argumentos con la función en la expresión de consulta:

Tags: sql, ms-access

Al ejecutar una consulta en `Access` me da el siguiente error:

> Se utilizó un número incorrecto de argumentos con la función en la
>   expresión de consulta:
>   'ph.hores-getHoresTimesheets(ph.cod_treb,ph.data_inici,ph.data_fi,ph.id_justificacio".

El codigo SQL de la consulta es:

```
SELECT ph.cod_treb, 
       t.nom_treb, 
       ph.exercici, 
       ph.data_inici, 
       ph.data_fi, 
       ph.hores AS hores_inicials, 
       ph.hores - Gethorestimesheets(ph.cod_treb, ph.data_inici, ph.data_fi, ph.id_justificacio) AS hores_pendents, 
       ph.id, 
       ph.cod_proj, 
       p.acronim, 
       ph.id_justificacio, 
       ph.id_activitat, 
       ph.activitat 
FROM   (planificacio_hores AS ph 
        LEFT JOIN treballadors AS t 
               ON t.cod_treb = ph.cod_treb) 
       LEFT JOIN projectes AS p 
              ON p.cod_proj = ph.cod_proj;
```

Comment: Buenas bimmer, bienvenid@. Pues tal y como te dice el error, demasiados parametros en GetHoresTimeSheets. Mira la funcion a ver cuantos deberias pasar porque estas pasando 4

Comment: Gracias! El problema es que estaba pasando 4 y necesitaba 5

Comment: @bimmer55, bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), si has encontrado una solución, por favor publícala y [marca tu propia respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) o [acepta la respuesta de otro usuario](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) que haya solucionado tu problema. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Del [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/21634/bimmer55) del autor;

> Gracias! El problema es que estaba pasando 4 y necesitaba 5

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/33531)

Comment: No añadas “gracias” como respuesta. En cambio, vota a favor de las respuestas que encuentres útiles. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/33531)

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave: ¿Lo que quieres decier es que se quite `Gracias!`?

Comment: @Rubén, así es, tienes razón.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave: Lo taché pero luego lo revertí porque tu comentario de revisión correspondería a una respuesta que sólo indique gracias. En este caso se trata de una cita en la que el OP indica cómo resolvió su proglema.

Comment: @toledano: Discrepo en que no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta, podría ser una respuesta inútil, en cuyo caso debería recibir un voto negativo en lugar de un voto de eliminación.